# error appending child as element whose innerHTML I just created

Tags: javascript, html

At the end of running this script, I should see the originally empty div id="checkboxes" becomes:

```
<div id="checkboxes">
      <label><input type="checkbox">option1</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox">option2</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox">option3</label>
</div>
```

How I tried to obtain this was (because I have the exact options in an array):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function populate() {
        debugger;
        var x = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
        var optionArray = ["option1", "option2", "option2"];


        for (var option of optionArray) {
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox'>" + option;
            x.appendChild = label;
        }
    }

    populate();


</script>

<html>
<head>
        <div id="checkboxes">
        </div>

</head>
</html>
```

I get an error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'appendChild' of null

at the line where I try to append the child, can someone advise why please

Comment: Why do you have `<div>`s in your `<head>`? Where is your `<script>`? Read [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

```
//x.appendChild = label;
x.appendChild(label);
```

Comment: Sorry but it still says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: It should work. check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2rse108h/

Comment: @Young Kyun Jin Always give some explanation about your answer. Otherwise it will treat as a low quality post and it may got deleted from admin.

Comment: It worked after I moved the script below the html. Thank you!

Comment: @hhdr103hhdr103 that is what the answer is given in the link provided by Xufox in comment